# Need to export all queries that are getting fired in a page

Tags: importing-exporting, database

I need to export all the queries that are getting fired in a page. Is there any way to get that ?

I tried Devel's query log. It writes all the queries in Drupal Temporary file system as a txt file. But the format is in json. Also, it does not seem to write the actual query, it seems to be writing the query object directly.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the query log (recommended), write your own solution, or enable query logging on the MySQL server. The fact that Devel uses JSON as output is not a valid reason to not use it

Comment: thanks, Clive. Just thought whether there could be a better solution, rather than writing my own solution.